# Which part of the following code will run at the server side

Tags: ignite

I am loading data from mysql into Ignite cache with following code. The code is run with client mode Ignite and will load the data into Ignite cluster.

I would ask:

1. Which parts of the code will run at the server side?
2. The working mechanism of loading data into cache looks like map-reduce, so, what tasks are sent to the server? the sql?
3. I would particularlly ask: will the following code run at the client side or the server sdie?

   CacheConfiguration cfg = StudentCacheConfig.cache("StudentCache", storeFactory);
   IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);

Following is the full code that loads the data into cache

```
public class LoadStudentIntoCache {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ignition.setClientMode(false);
        String configPath = "default-config.xml";
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(configPath);
        CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory storeFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Integer, Student>();
        storeFactory.setDialect(new MySQLDialect());
        IDataSourceFactory factory = new MySqlDataSourceFactory();

        storeFactory.setDataSourceFactory(new Factory<DataSource>() {
            public DataSource create() {
                try {
                    DataSource dataSource = factory.createDataSource();
                    return dataSource;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
        //
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Student> cfg = StudentCacheConfig.cache("StudentCache", storeFactory);
        IgniteCache<Integer, Student> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);

        List<String> sqls = new ArrayList<String>();
        sqls.add("java.lang.Integer");
        sqls.add("select id, name, birthday  from db1.student where id < 1000" );
        sqls.add("java.lang.Integer");
        sqls.add("select id, name, birthday  from db1.student where id >= 1000 and id < 1000" );
        cache.loadCache(null, , sqls.toArray(new String[0]));

        Student s = cache.get(1);
        System.out.println(s.getName() + "," + s.getBirthday());
        ignite.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed here will be executed within your application, there is no magic happening. Usually it's a client node, however in your case it's started in server mode (probably by mistake): `Ignition.setClientMode(false)`.

The data loading process will happen on each server node. I.e. each server node will execute SQL queries provided to load the data from the DB.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin, Yes, I meant to run in client mode. I update my question. It looks to me that CacheConfiguration and all its dependent classes (Exception KV Pojo of the Cache), like datasourcefactory, datatypetransformer should be present in the server node's classpath

Comment: In my code pasted in the question, I am using inner class for `storeFactory.setDataSourceFactory`, it leads to me that I have to put LoadStudentIntoCache  in the server's classpath which is ugly, I should have created a standalone class that makes it independent of LoadStudentIntoCache

Comment: Yes, anonymous classes are evil for distributed systems :) You're right, factory will be invoked on server side and its class must be deployed there.